# My Database Design Flaw...Explain a better way PLEASE.... ((Correct Way))

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

First lets start off with I am writing a program in VB.net and have a database set up and everything works fine as of now. The program is user based and requires the user to log into the program and it will show them all of there user information, orders, settings, fees etc,  etc... and everything that is needed. The issue I have is right now I have each user set up with a different database. I have the user login and connect to a database that just holds the Users and initial program start up settings. Along with this it loads the users database address and password into the program so I can then access there database and pull from all the tables relating to them.

I feel that having a database for each user is a bit overboard but each database pertains to the specific person and the information can be sensitive including address, amount of money made, and many other things so I don't know how to set it up to be most productive because if i have 50 users I don't want to create 50 databases.

Please help with this. Even if you just point me to several places to read and learn I would love that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can create different users for a single database and then grant those users specific permissions (e.g., user "Bob" can only view bobs_table).

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but are you saying just make everyone there own tables? If so I don't know how I would accomplish that. Right now in each database I currently use 8 different tables per user.

Comment: You can grant a user permission to access whatever you'd like. You could give a user permission to access 0 tables, 1 table, or 8 tables. You can create new users with `CREATE USER` and you give them permission to access the data with `GRANT`. Here is a MySQL reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 0):

Creating seprate db for each user is not a way to go. You have create a new user table in 1 db and add userid in your ref tables. Below is an example how to achieve this

```
User - Userid, UserName, Pwd etc.
Address - Userid, Addressid, HouseNum, StreetName, City etc.
Shipping details - Userid, Shippingid, Shippingdate etc.
```

In all your queries based on Userid pull data specific to the logged in user. 
Also you should always connect to your db using some service account from your application. Validate if user is authenticated or not using some stored proc or query.

Comment: I'm not going to lie. I'm very new MySql and databases. How would I use the service account to validate if the user is valid or not? Currently the way I have it set up is the user has to type in a valid username and password in order to access the program. It then takes the database address and password from the users database and stores them for future reference in the program. That was my way of validating. If you could point me in the way of some material on how to achieve what you're saying I would be happy to read it and learn it.

Comment: In general scenario there will be two type of users...1. db users which are created to have access on your db...they are logical users (or group) not real peoples. generally 2 or 3 users are created for this purpose like admin, normal and readonly users. 2. Application users are your actual users (people who will access your application). There enteries are done in User table in your db.  So to make connection b/w ur app and db would be done by db user. But actual queries would fired against your app users (real users).